# angularjs - ui-router - only call function when certain subpage loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ui-router` to route control a page with multiple sub pages that share the same controller:

```
.state('users.create', {
      url: "/create",
      views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'pages/users.html',
                controller : 'UsersCtrl'
                    },
                'main@users': { 
                    templateUrl: 'pages/users.new.html',
                    controller : 'UsersCtrl', parent:'users'},
                'list@users': { 
                    templateUrl: 'pages/users.list.html',
                    controller: 'UsersCtrl', parent:'users' }
            }
    })
```

At the moment whenever I call `users.create`, `UsersCtrl` will be called 3 times. 
and I have a specific function `updateListButton()` in `UsersCtrl` that only useful to `pages/users.list.html`.

How can I specifically call `updateListButton()` whenever I want to update `pages/users.list.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan but a possible solution could be to use `ng-init` in the root HTML element of `pages/users.list.html` like so:

```
<div ng-init='updateListButton()'>
    <h1>Users List</h1>
</div>
```

But take into account that (as per the [AngularJD Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)):

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.